Having problems with model.summary() in tensorflow
I am currently using tensorflow version 2.15.0 and building a project with LSTM RNN, but even after building the model, i am getting the model summary to be unbuilt. I was trying to execute it locally with jupyter notebook, but got the same error. This error is with both, tensorflow 2.15.0 and 2.16.0
Can anyone please help with this?
model
summary of the model
Should i try to use lower version of tensorflow?
